# Is it possible to retrieve list of events signature/name of a Contract Address?

Tags: web3js, events

I have a contract address and its ABI. How can I retrieve all the events emitted by the contract?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ABI file, you could get all the event names from it in JavaScript as follows:

```js
const eventNames = abi.filter(item => item.type === "event")
                      .map(item => item.name)
```

If you want the entire event signatures, you could do the following:

```js
const eventSignatures = abi.filter(item => item.type === "event")
                      .map(item => `${item.name}(${item.inputs.map(i => `${i.type}${i.indexed?" indexed ":" "}${i.name}`).join(", ")})`)
```

The code above would returns something like the following:

```json
[
   "Borrow(address indexed account, address indexed bond, uint256 borrowAmount)",
   "DepositCollateral(address indexed account, address indexed collateral, uint256 collateralAmount)",
   "LiquidateBorrow(address indexed liquidator, addres…dress collateral, uint256 seizedCollateralAmount)",
   "RepayBorrow(address indexed payer, address indexed…bond, uint256 repayAmount, uint256 newDebtAmount)",
   "SetOracle(address indexed owner, address oldOracle, address newOracle)",
   "TransferOwnership(address indexed oldOwner, address indexed newOwner)",
   "WithdrawCollateral(address indexed account, address indexed collateral, uint256 collateralAmount)"
]
```

If you don't have the ABI file of the contract address, you could use Etherscan's API to pull the ABI of the verified contract as shown here: [How to dynamically load contracts data with their ABI from etherscan API?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/61821/how-to-dynamically-load-contracts-data-with-their-abi-from-etherscan-api)